# Using HTML tags in swipe pages?

Tags: android, html, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm doing an Android app with swipe screen. I did the following tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#fragment

I want to use html tags to do some editing to the text in my string values. I want to be able to do paragraphs and bold characters. But I do not know how and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Normally I just use this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.instruct)));
```

However I don't understand how I can do that with a Fragment class and ViewPager.

The following is my Fragment class:

```
public class InstructSSPageFrag1 extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.instruct, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the instructionactivity_screen_slide.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is my Fragment activity and adapter and pager adapter:

```
    public class InstructionActivity extends FragmentActivity{

        private static final int NUM_PAGES=5;

        private ViewPager mPager;

        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.instructionactivity_screen_slide);


            // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        }

        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, select the previous step.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            }
        }

        private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
            public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return new InstructSSPageFrag1();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NUM_PAGES;
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible to use html tags for Fragment class/Viewpager?

EDIT: I tried using the piece of code from Atul O Holic

```
public class InstructSSPageFrag1 extends Fragment{
    private TextView tvFrag;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.instruct, container, false);
        String text = getActivity().getString(R.string.instructionstring);
        tvFrag.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        return rootView;
    }
```

However it is causing a force close when I go into the fragment. Here are the errors:

```
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at com.apps.swipeapp.InstructSSPageFrag1.onCreateView(InstructSSPageFrag1.java:18)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
03-20 16:14:06.329: E/AndroidRuntime(7039):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First access the string from the strings.xml file using the context inside your Fragment.

```
 String text = getActivity().getString(R.string.yourString);
```

Then apply the formatting in the usual way you follow.

```
 myFragmentTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

You can do that in one line as well. Hope this helps. :)

**Edit:**

Initialize your TextView,

```
tvFrag = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
```

and then do,

```
tvFrag.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code but it seems to be causing an error whenever I go to the fragment activity. I've updated my question with what I've added and the error.